# Is it possible to skip loop iterations for itertools.product() if i know the ID of the iteration?

Tags: python, loops, intertools

I have the following code:

```
import math
import numpy as np
import itertools

s = [  0,   1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8,   9,  10,  11,  12,
       13,  14,  15,  16,  17,  18,  19,  20,  21,  22,  23,  24,  25,
       26,  27,  28,  29,  30,  31,  32,  33,  34,  35,  36,  37,  38,
       39,  40,  41,  42,  43,  44,  45,  46,  47,  48,  49,  50]

def variate4(l):
    yield from itertools.product(*([l] * 4))

for i in variate4(s):
    print(repr(''.join(str(i))))
```

The result of execution is all possible four-digit combinations of numbers from the `s` array.
For example: (12, 32, 46, 50).
As i see, there is always the same order in results.

Is it possible to generate combination by its id?
I mean result number 4856 for example.

I tried this way:

```
j = 0
for i in variate4(s):
    j = j + 1
    if j == 4856:
        print(repr(''.join(str(i))))
        break
```

But still have to wait until all previous combinations are generated.
I'm trying to achieve instant jump to the desired iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iteratively take the modulo of the list size from the given id and dividing the id by the list size for the next iteration:

```
def variate_from_id(l, id, n=4):
    combination = []
    id -= 1 # since your id starts from 1
    size = len(s)
    for _ in range(n):
        combination.append(l[id % size])
        id //= size
    return tuple(reversed(combination))
```

so that:

```
variate_from_id(s, 4856)
```

returns:

```
(0, 1, 44, 10)
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/WgTxZ8